# How do I make Cypher respect character encoding when using LOAD CSV in browser?

Tags: character-encoding, neo4j, load-csv

My case: List of Danish-named students (with names including characters as ü,æ,ø,å). Minimal Working Example
CSV file:

```
Fornavn;Efternavn;Mobil;Adresse
Øjvind;Ørnenæb;87654321;Paradisæblevej 125, 5610 Åkirkeby
Süzette;Ågård;12345678;Ærøvej 123, 2000 Frederiksberg
```

In-browser neo4j-editor:

```
$ LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS  FROM 'file:///path/to/file.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ";"
CREATE (:Elev {fornavn: line.Fornavn, efternavn: line.Efternavn, mobil: line.Mobilnr, adresse: line.Adresse})
```

Resulting in registrations like:
[Neo4j browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuCtz.png), containing ?-characters, where Danish/German characters are wanted. My data come from a Learning Management System into Excel. When exporting as CSV from Excel, I can control file encoding as a function of the Save As dialogue box. I have tried encoding from Excel as "UTF-8" (which [the Neo4j manual says](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.1/query-load-csv.html) it wants), "ISO-Western European", "Windows-Western European", "Unicode" in separately named file, and adjusted the `FROM 'file:///path/to/file.csv'` clause accordingly.

Intriguingly, exactly the same misrepresentation results, independent of which (apparent?) file encoding, I request from Excel when "Saving As". When Copy-pasting the names and addresses directly into the editor, I do not encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Michael Hunger's blog post here](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/10/load-cvs-with-success/) which contains some tips, namely:

> if you use non-ascii characters (umlauts, accents etc.) make sure to use the appropriate locale or provide the System property `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Comment: Seems like this won't do the trick:
`:GET /db/manage/server/jmx/domain/org.neo4j/instance%3Dkernel%230%2Cname%3DConfiguration` gives me
`[
  {
    "description": "The configuration parameters used to configure Neo4j",
    "name": "org.neo4j:instance=kernel#0,name=Configuration",
    "attributes": [{...},
      {
        "description": "Configuration attribute",
        "name": "-Dfile.encoding",
        "value": "UTF8",
        "isReadable": "true",
        "type": "java.lang.String",
        "isWriteable": "false ",
        "isIs": "false "
      },...`

Comment: Even though I interpret the above `:GET` feedback as the file encoding is already set correctly, I still get unwanted output. I will take a look at the [Hunger blog](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/10/load-cvs-with-success/) mentioned by @FrobberOfBits.